# Trouble with rails 3.1 project deployed on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript

For some reason my `.js.coffee` files in my project are not being called through the `:remote => true` links/forms

I'm trying to call the `posts/new` controller via Ajax. The controller is being called and executed but it can't find to where to redirect.

In the log I get the following message:

> ActionView:MissingTemplate (Missing template posts/new, application/new with {:handlers => [:erb, :builders], :formats => [:js, :html], :locale => [:en, :en]}. searched in: * "/app/app/views"

When I change my `new.js.coffee` file to `new.js` it works fine. Any idea what to do so I can run Coffee script files too?

**UPDATE**

My Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :deployment do
    gem 'pg'
end

gem 'devise', '1.4.9'
gem 'omniauth', '1.0.0'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'rails_autolink'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your `gem 'coffee-rails'` line outside of the `:assets` groups, maybe down after your `jquery-rails` gem line. The `:assets` gems don't get used during production.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I was getting crazy on why an AJAX call was working locally but on Heroku it was trying to render the HTML view instead of the JS. This has solved it!